# case sensitivity on Mac for file_exists()?

Tags: php, macos, mamp, file-exists

First off, Mac OS X is not my native operating system but since I'm comfortable in Ubuntu, it's been an easy transition for the most part.

Being that it's Unix-based, I was under the impression this os was case-sensitive, but the `file_exists()` function is saying otherwise.

In my htdocs file, i have these 2 files:

test.php

MyFiLeWiThMiXeDCaSe.php

In test.php, i have this code:

```
if(file_exists('myfilewithmixedcase.php')) {
  echo 'exists';
} else {
  echo 'doesnt exist';
}

// ouputs: exists
```

Anyone know how/why this is happening? This is causing a problem because when we deploy code like this to a linux OS, `file_exists()` is returning false.

BTW: I'm using MAMP PRO as the local web server.

Comment: Not an answer to your current question, but it's easy to create a small extra partition that has a case-sensitive file-system and mount that since the default filesystem on osx allows resizing. Put your web projects on that partition to prevent yourself from creating case-sensitivity related bugs/issues. Just watch out with your apache paths if you decide to create a symlink to your new partition.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, it sounds like if i create a partition for my htdocs folder, it should minimize this issue substantially.

Comment: You can write you a case sensitivity version of file_exists() yourself.   You can first get the file list of the parent directory,and check if current file is in it with case sensitivity compare.

Answer (score 5):

Despite being a BSD derivative OS X is NOT case sensitive. Or rather HFs and HFS+ filesystems are not, unless you chose the case sensitive option when formatting your disk. This is usually not done because many applications have issues with this (Adobe, MS, etc.) - or at least they did the last time i tried it under Tiger.

Answer (score 3):

The default filesystem on OS X is case-insensitive HFS+.

You can format a volume as case-sensitive HFS+, and there are (dirty) ways of enabling case-sensitivity for existing volumes. But, these will break existing software, and you should avoid case-sensitivity on your root volume.

If you need a case-sensitive filesystem for some reason (e.g. building Android requires it), you can make an appropriately-formatted disk image using Disk Utility.

Note that the UNIX foundation of OS X will work just fine with a case-sensitive filesystem.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. If my disk utility says Format : Mac OS Extended (Journaled), does that mean it's currently case-insensitive?

Comment: Yes. Case-sensitive filesystems are specially denoted in Disk Utility. (You can make one easily by creating a new disk image.)

Answer (score 1):

By default, Mac OS X is not case-sensitive, so "FILE" and "file" are two names for the same file.